# Angular 2 build tool preferences

Tags: javascript, angular, gulp

I am going to start a large scale project and going to use Angular 2 for front end.

As today, angular2 looks pretty fast ui framework allthough its still in RC we going to use it.

But the question is what should do for build front end process....

I mean to say as we have AngularCli ready to use for creating production js files...

So in that case what will be the good thing to go with...

1. angular cli
2. go with some custom self developed gulp command...

can anybody please suggest right option? or more than that which help for long term..

Comment: Which one would be the best for you and your team? I'd suggest using that one.

Comment: Using a release candidate on "a large scale project" doesn't sound like a great technical decision to me. It's a very risky decision. Why not use React & Redux or Angular 1.5 with ES6 and components? They're both battle tested and more importantly not release candidates.

Comment: @Seth   your suggestion sounds good

Answer (score 1):

Angular 2 is live now and angular cli also released a latest version which uses most reliable build model in web development named as 'web pack'.

I would recommend use this in case if you are using any other build model for your project.More over this supports AOT compilation which can be icing on the cake

Answer (score 0):

I had a little experience with both ways and found out that angular-cli is better. My arguments:

1)You know, to add a simple dependency to angular-cli project you have to add it in several places (package.json, angular-cli.build.js, system-config.ts). While I was creating gulp build I had to create similar mechanism to make gulp clear what files to compile. It is possible, but system will be rather complicated. If I create such system, I'm not sure that next developer will understand it well and fast.

2)Angular-cli is not so comfortable system for me, especially I don't like the way of adding dependencies, but it is active project connected with angular. It will be supported and become better. I'm not afraid to stay alone with angular-cli, community always will help.